# Windows environment variables not recognized

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables

I'm trying to set some windows environment variables. But for some reason after saving my variable it still can't be used in cmd.

For example PHP:
[image: php environment variable]

The error I keep getting:

`'D:\xampp\php\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
program or batch file.`

I used the Browse File... button to select the `php.exe` application just to make sure I didn't make any typos. Also I tried to change the value to `D:\xampp\php\` this didn't work either.

Restarting windows didn't help. Also typing just `D:\xampp\php\php.exe` works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Be able to more easily run `php.exe` from `cmd.exe`? How are you using your environment variable?

Comment: yes I'm trying to use PHP in cmd and also some other programs. It always used to work until my last windows clean install.

Comment: And you're using it as `%PHP%`? Modifying `%PATH%` is likely a better option.

Comment: @Chris no thats it %php% works but before this I could just use php without the percent. Do you have any idea how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `php` without specifying its full path you should modify `%PATH%` (or create a new `%PATH%` user variable):

```
D:\xampp\php;%PATH%
```

`%PATH%` tells the operating system which directories to search when you try to run things. Make sure to log out and back in after changing this variable.

See also https://superuser.com/q/317631/312289